# Button is now working to change the from intro to match page

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I was trying to build a rock paper scissor game using HTML CSS and JS but the fade-out effect to travel from intro class to match class is not working when I press the button.

I don't know where I went wrong.

Code:

```js
const game = () => {
  let pScore = 0;
  let cScore = 0;

  // Start the Game
  const startGame = () => {
    const playBtn = document.querySelector(".intro button");
    const introScreen = document.querySelector(".intro");
    const match = document.querySelector(".match");

    playBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
      introScreen.classList.add("fadeOut");
      match.classList.add("fadeIn");
    });
  }


  //call all the inner functions
  startGame();
};

//start the game function
game();
```

```html
<body>
  <section class="game">
    <div class="score">
      <div class="player-score">
        <h2>Player</h2>
        <p>0</p>
      </div>
      <div class="computer-score">
        <h2>Computer</h2>
        <p>0</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="intro">
      <h1>Rock Paper Scissors</h1>
      <button>Start</button>
    </div>
    <div class="match fadeOut">
      <h2 class="winner">Choose your weapon</h2>
      <div class="hands">
        <img class="player-hand" src="./asset/rock.png" alt="rock">
        <img class="computer-hand" src="./asset/rock.png" alt="rock">
      </div>
      <div class="options">
        <button class="rock">rock</button>
        <button class="paper">paper</button>
        <button class="scissors">scissors</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </section>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you have CSS or Javascript to handle the fadeOut/fadeIn animations? If you don't then that's 100% the reason it's not working because if you inspect the DOM you can see those classes get added when you click the button.